# custom function to display colored math content in Typst

Tags: colors, scripting, typst

I want to create a custom function in Typst that allows me to color content inside of the math mode, for example `s^+` in a color specified in a parameter (the content should of course be a parameter as well).

So my attempt is based on [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/typst/comments/1684fa3/command_for_coloring_text_in_math_mode/), but the parameter for the color is missing in the answer.
My best solution is `#let colMath(x, color) = text(fill: color)[$#x$]`, but then I have to call it using something like `#colMath($s_2^-$, red)`, even if the function call is in math mode already. When I remove the # I can also remove the `$s_2^-$`, but then it says "the variable red is not defined".
I guess part of the problem is that I don't really understand when to use the # and when not.

Thank you for any help or advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error occurs because variables like `red` are only defined in the typst code mode, not math mode. You can get around this by defining `red` as a variable in your outer scope, i.e. with `#let red = red`. Since inner scopes (the math mode) can access all variables at outer levels, this no longer relies on builtin names being accessible and instead treats it like any other variable/function/etc.

Another way is to simply enter markup mode using `#red` in the function call.

In sum: your understanding of `#` is correct -- it enters code mode, which exposes `red` and similar builtins. When math mode is active, you have to declare those variables explicitly in your outer scope *or* enter markup mode to use the builtin definition.

```
#let colMath(x, color) = text(fill: color)[$#x$]

// Define your own variable
#let red = red
$a x^2 + b x + c colMath(s_2^-, red)$

// Or simply enter markup mode inside the function call:
$a x^2 + b x + c colMath(s_2^-, #red)$
```

Comment: Interesting. So do you know a reason why this variables are only defined in the typst code mode?

Comment: It's the same reason the `nabla` variable is only defined in math mode -- the typst authors thought it is only useful in that context. If enough people want to use colors in math mode, they might support including those variables in the future 

Comment: There is no need to redefine `red` like this. You can indeed use it the way you wanted to in the first place, directly in math mode, but you will have to add a `#` in front of `red` so it doesnt get treated as a math variable name: `$colMath(s_2, #red)$`

Comment: My understanding of the original question was how to get around requiring `#` in the calling code. That's why it is redefined, to avoid dropping into code mode

Comment: No, I think the original problem was that adding `#` to call the whole function requires you to enter math mode again inside the parameters and without it, the `red` part errored. So this is how the `#red` part doesnt error when calling the function without `#` in front and not having to reenter math mode.

Comment: @xkevio I incorporated your feedback in to the answer, thanks.